# In Solr, how do i know page number?

Tags: solr, pagination

> If i have one pdf file in solr, how do i know page number of search result
>   in original pdf file?
>
> It means there is pdf file.
>
> Contents of 1page are 'abc mart's other name is abc'.
>
> Contents of 2page are 'abc song is good'.
>
> Contents of 3page are 'I like google'.
>
> After i search 'abc', there are list of 'abc'.
>
> Do i represent page number?
>
> ex ) i want list '1page abc / 1page abc / 2page abc'.
>
> Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to index every page as a separate document in order to do this.

Additionally, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15116160/get-page-numbers-of-searchresult-of-a-pdf-in-solr) SO post for more details.

Answer (score 0):

You have to index it seprately in multi valued field with main id and doc id seprat so that ou can serch to a perticular page